# Grayscale image using opencv from numpy array failed

Tags: numpy, opencv

I use the following numpy array that hold an image which is black and white image with the following shape

```
print(img.shape)

(28, 112)
```

when I try to grayscale the image, to use it to get contours using opencv with following steps

```
#grayscale the image
 grayed = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

 #thredshold image
 thresh = cv2.threshold(grayed, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

I got the following error

```
<ipython-input-178-7ebff17d1c18> in get_digits(img)
      6 
      7     #grayscale the image
----> 8     grayed = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      9 
     10 

error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11073: error: (-215) depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5 in function cv::cvtColor
```

the opencv errors have no information in it to be able to get what is wrong

Comment: your image is already grayscale i.e. black and white having shape (28, 112)

Comment: If `img` has shape (28, 112), it is not a color BGR image.  It is already gray scale.  (BGR or RGB would have shape (28, 112, 3).)

Comment: yes, it is black and white but the thredshold function of cv2 require it to be grayscaled in some way, how can I achieve that?

Comment: the following call 
thresh = cv2.threshold(grayed, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
will fail if I give it the black and white image with the following error
src.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) in function cv::threshold

Comment: again errors that doesn't make any sense, and explain nothing

Comment: Ok, now I converted it back to 3 channel image, but still, I got the same error

`img = np.stack((img,) * 3,-1)
    img = img.astype(np.float64)   
    img *= 1./255
    print(img.shape)
`
now the shape is `(28, 112, 3)`

but still  
`grayed = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

gives the same error 

`color.cpp:11073: error: (-215) depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5 in function cv::cvtColor`

Comment: Ok, we are making progress here :) 

I changed float64 to float32 and the grayscale problem goes away, now I'm stuck on the threshold issue

`img = np.stack((img,) * 3,-1)
    img = img.astype(np.float32)   
    img *= 1./255
    print(img.shape)
    plt.imshow(img)

    #grayscale the image
    grayed = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #thredshold image
    thresh = cv2.threshold(grayed, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]`
thresh.cpp:1406: error: (-215) src.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) in function cv::threshold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the working code for how you were trying it:

```
img = np.stack((img,) * 3,-1)
img = img.astype(np.uint8)
grayed = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(grayed, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

**A simpler way of getting the same result is to invert the image yourself:**

```
img = (255-img)
thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

As you discovered, as you perform different operations on images, the image is required to be in different formats.

cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV and cv2.THRESH_BINARY are designed to take a color image (and convert it to grayscale) so you need a three channel representation.

cv2.THRESH_OTSU works with grayscale images so one channel is okay for that.

Since your image was already grayscale from the start, you weren't able to convert it from color to grayscale nor did you really need to. I assume you were trying to invert the image but that's easy enough on your own (`255-img`).

At one point you tried to do an cv2.THRESH_OTSU with floating point values but cv2.THRESH_OTSU requires integers between 0 and 255.

If openCV had more user-friendly error messages it would really help with issues like these.